# How are ClientRequest & ClientHttpRequest connected in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux

When we use `WebClient` API from `spring-webflux`, it internally uses `ClientRequest` class

But we also have `ClientHttpRequest` in the `spring-web` module

Why do we have two different classes that sound & are very similar. Can someone explain the differences between these two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest` is meant to be the class that Spring developers can use in with the `WebClient`. It's got advanced features like a request attributes map, a logPrefix for logging purposes, static builders, etc. It is also using higher level concepts like `ExchangeStrategies`.

On the other hand, `org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest` is the base abstraction for HTTP client requests, at the raw HTTP level. This is used to implement the various adaptation layers for HTTP clients (Reactor Netty, Jetty).

So unless you're doing with low level stuff, you shouldn't need to use `ClientHttpRequest` directly in your application.